# Basic arithmetic grammar -- handling parentheses

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have written the following to handle basic binary operations in arithmetic:

```
grammar Calc;

expression
    : OPERAND (BIN_OP expression)*
    ;

// 12 or .12 or 2. or 2.38
OPERAND
    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)?
    | '.' [0-9]+
    ;

BIN_OP
    : [-+/*]
    ;
```

Now I can do things like:

```
0.9+2.4*3.6
```

However, how is order-of-operations and parentheses normally handled with antlr? For example:

- What if I wanted to write `(0.9+2.4)*3.6` instead, how could I do that?
- Or, what if I wanted to write `((0.9+2.4)*3.6)` ?
- And finally, to catch an invalid case of un-matched parens, `(((((0.9+2.4)*3.6))` ?

How is that normally handled in antlr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the really nice things that ANTLR4 brought was the ability to easily represent precedence by the ordering of alternatives in a rule.

Try something like:

```
grammar Calc;

expression
    : '(' expression ')' # parenExpr
    : expression (MUL_OP | DIV_OP) expression # mulDivExpr
    : expression (ADD_OP | SUB_OP) expressions # addSubExpr
    : OPERAND # operandExpr
    ;

// 12 or .12 or 2. or 2.38
OPERAND
    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)?
    | '.' [0-9]+
    ;

SUB_OP: '-';
ADD_OP: '+';
DIV_OP: '/';
MUL_OP: '*';
    ;
```

Comment: @Cool! Out of curiosity, why did you break up the expressions into `mulDiv` and `addSub` ?

Comment: oh! I see, it's the statement you made that says `easily represent precedence by the ordering of alternatives in a rule`, so placing `mulDiv` first gives it higher order of operations, correct?

Comment: right, and they are both at the same precedence level.

Comment: Got it, thank you. And then why does the solo-`operand` rule go to the end, is that just so the leaf-nodes get pushed to the end of the parse tree, i.e., the operand values themselves?

Comment: The order of the `operandExpr` and `parenExpr` alternatives are not really significant (as there's no precedence ambiguity.  This is just a pretty common order to see (parens at top), precedence rules, and token matches at the bottom.